# How can I create a balanced subset based on one variable in r?

Tags: r, subset

In my data I want to explain what influences an offline or an online conversion. However, my data is unbalanced. I have 12344 online conversions and 435 offline conversion. Due to this I get warnings when I want to run my logistic regresssion.

To solve this I want to take a more balanced subset to use in my logistic regressions, but I have no idea how I can manage this.

My data looks like:

```
Client id        Conversion_type
    1                Online
    2                Offline
    3                Online
    4                Online
    5                Online
    6                Online
    7                Online
```

So based on the conversiontype I want to have a more balanced subset.

Comment: Maybe this helps : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DMwR/versions/0.4.1/topics/SMOTE

Comment: Which warnings you get? Never heard that you have to use only balanced datasets to run logistic regression.

Comment: I get this one: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Comment: @ maydin How do you need to interpret the perc.over and perc.under. I don't really get that when I read the description in the rdocumentation? When I want to use it i get: Error in SMOTE(cOffline_conversion ~ Number_of_touchpoints + Types_used_cat +  : 
  unused arguments (perc.over = 600, k = 5, perc.under = 100, learner = NULL). Not sure if what i do wrong

Comment: Try the ROSE function in the ROSE package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the data frame by `Conversion_type` and then sample randomly from the data frame that contains the `online` Conversion type so many samples as there are samples for the `offline` conversion type:

```
library(dplyr)
df_online <- df %>% 
  filter(Conversion_type == "Online")

df_offline <- df %>% 
  filter(Conversion_type == "Offline")


df_online_sampled <- df_online[sample(nrow(df_online), nrow(df_offline)), ]

balanced_df <- bind_rows(df_online_sampled, df_offline)
```

However I think the problem in your case might be that the classes are perfectly separable, see e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression) on how to adress this.

Comment: df_online <- Client_level %>% 
  filter(Client_level$conversion_type == "online")

df_offline <- Client_level %>% 
  filter(Client_level$conversion_type == "offline")


df_online_sampled <- Client_level[sample(nrow(Client_level), nrow(df_offline)), ]

balanced_df <- rbind(df_online_sampled, df_offline, fill=TRUE) 

If I run this i get the same df as i had before, so its not balanced. Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Yeah sorry you are right, there was an error in my code, the sampling should be `df_online_sampled <- df_online[sample(nrow(df_online), nrow(df_offline)), ] ` also see my updated answer, I don't think that unbalanced data is your problem.